Is it illegal to share a recording of someone else's private conversation?
Can a private conversation that has been recorded without the knowledge of any involved in the conversation. Then shared in a text message amongst 20+ people be considered illegal? It was shared to bully us and make fun of us.

How was this recorded without the knowledge of any of the parties involved? Wasn't the person recording it in the conversation?

Was this a telephone conversation or just a group of people talking out in the open?

VTC for lack of clarity, and DV for apparent disinterest of the OP based on lack of engagement with answers and comments.

What do you mean by “private”?
If you mean a conversation that the participants did not want overhead but was conducted in a way that allowed others to overhear, then that is not illegal.
If you mean a conversation conducted where there was a reasonable expectation of privacy and where the eavesdropper would need to go to some effort to overhear, then that may be a breach of privacy and there may be legal remedies.
In both cases, the circumstances matter. A loud domestic argument conducted in a private home might not be private if it can be easily heard outside. Similarly, a whispered conversation in a public place might be private.
How was it recorded?
If I transcribe what you say by using pen and paper or typing, then unless I trespassed to overhear, I’m not invading your privacy.
If I record your conversation in person on my iPhone and I’m in a place where you don’t have a reasonable expectation of privacy, I’m probably not doing anything wrong.
However, if I use technical means to intercept your conversation, I might be breaking the law.


Is it illegal to share someone else's private conversation?

Not as a general rule.

Can a private conversation that has been recorded without the
knowledge of any involved in the conversation. Then shared in a text
message amongst 20+ people be considered illegal?

This is very likely to be legal. In short, there is no law against being mean to people. This is basically just gossiping, which is as old as time and has never been illegal, with a high tech twist.
Eavesdropping is not, as a general rule, illegal, and as a general rule, consent is not needed to record a conversation held in real life, even surreptitiously. The burden is generally on the speakers to keep their conversation out of earshot if they want privacy. The one-party consent recording statute in Indiana applies to telecommunications and not simply conversations in a semi-public place. See e.g., Ind. Code § 35-31.5-2-176 (applies to electronic communications that are intercepted only).
Under the federal Wiretap Act, it is illegal for any person to secretly record an oral, telephonic, or electronic communication that other parties to the communication reasonably expect to be private. (18 U.S.C. § 2511.) But, in a semi-public place where you can be overheard by someone without, for example, trespassing, there is no reasonable expectation of privacy. It also isn't at all clear that a mere recording of an oral conversation constitutes an "interception" within the meaning of that statute (as opposed, for example, to a parabolic pin point microphone that operates at long range and surely wasn't used here).
It isn't defamation because it was true. It didn't even portray you in a false light. It is troubling because it is true.
The recording wasn't made by someone with whom you have a confidential relationship who breached their duties to you like your priest or your lawyer.
It isn't a peeping tom video or revenge porn.
It wasn't distributed for commercial gain, so it wouldn't violate your right of publicity.
It wasn't recorded by you in a tangible medium and then copied, so it wouldn't be a copyright violation.
There is no indication in the question that an illegal wiretap was involved.
It is conceivable that some things that could fall under the definition of "bullying" would constitute extortion (e.g. forcing you to give them money). But if it was simply done to make fun of you and emotionally make you feel bad without forcing you to do something, that is unlikely to be illegal.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Yes, it is illegal.
18 U.S.C. § 2511 states:

(1)Except as otherwise specifically provided in this chapter any person who—
(c)intentionally discloses, or endeavors to disclose, to any other person the contents of any wire, oral, or electronic communication, knowing or having reason to know that the information was obtained through the interception of a wire, oral, or electronic communication in violation of this subsection;


Unlikely that this circumstance constitutes an "interception" in the sense of the statute.

@ohwilleke, Give the specific wording in the question, it is actually more likely that the miscreants left a recording device in a secret location.  Because the question clearly specifies it was a private conversation, so there is no basis to believe that it occurred in a public place with no reasonable expectation of privacy as you have presumed.

I argue that it is a "semi-private place" in which they thought it was private but weren't careful enough, as opposed to a truly private place where there is a reasonable expectation of privacy, such as inside someone's own house.

@ohwilleke, argue away then, I will defer to the OP claiming it was private.  I will not modify further, and simply ask that they clarify "semi" vs "truly" if they feel inclined.

These days it's probably not hard to plant a bug in someone's house, although it seems extreme to do this just to embarass someone. There are also high-tech long distance eavesdropping devices, but that seems even more extreme.

@Barmar, this isn't the cold war, you don't need a CIA bug or "Q" from James Bond to craft you something.  There are all kinds of common consumer devices available that could easily record a conversation and not be considered "extreme" in any manner.  I have one in my pocket right now...

@MichaelHall If you're talking about your phone, don't you usually need to be within earshot of the conversation to record it? I'm assuming the "private conversation" took place somewhere like a private home, not in a bar with lots of other people about.

@Barmar I'd really rather not get into more speculation over presumed details...  But phones can be set to record audio or video and be left behind in a meeting place, there are lots of low cost WiFi security cameras, digital voice recorders, game cameras, etc. on the market.

I really think we need more details about the circumstances of the recording. I posted comments above asking the OP to clarify.
